# How can I make the STM32WB55 USB dongle show up in linux?

Tags: driver, stm32, udev

I have a [Nucleo Pack with two STM32WB55 discovery boards](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/p-nucleo-wb55.html). One of the boards has a 64 pin micro controller, while the other board is USB dongle with a 48 pin microcontroller.

I flashed the binary file from an example project called "BLE_p2pServer" found [here](https://my.st.com/content/my_st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32cube-mcu-mpu-packages/stm32cubewb.html) onto the 64 pin micro controller using "STM32CubeProgrammer" and the board communicated just fine with an app called "ST BLE Sensor" as suggested in [this tutorial](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group1/85/77/14/6a/ef/77/48/3d/DM00598021/files/DM00598021.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00598021.pdf).

Now I would like to flash the 48 pin USB dongle in order to make it communicate with the 64 pin board that is already working.

Unfortunately the USB dongle doesn't show up in "STM32CubeProgrammer" and flashing an example project from TrueStudio also results in an error:

```
    ST-Link enumeration failed
    Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
    Reason: ST-LINK DLL error.
```

The boards have different names:

```
    chandran@chandran-OptiPlex-9020:~$ lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 038: ID 0483:5740 STMicroelectronics STM32F407
    Bus 001 Device 039: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1 (Nucleo-F103RB)
```

Both boards have the same microcontroller (STM32WB55), but maybe the USB dongle requires different udev rules?

The st-related drivers are missing in my "/dev" folder when I unplug the 64 pin discovery board and leave the 48 pin dongle connected.

When boards are connected:

```
    chandran@chandran-OptiPlex-9020:~$ ll /dev/stlinkv2-1_*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3 Dec 30 18:32 /dev/stlinkv2-1_ -> sdb
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Dec 30 18:32 /dev/stlinkv2-1_0 -> bsg/6:0:0:0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7 Dec 30 18:32 /dev/stlinkv2-1_1 -> ttyACM1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3 Dec 30 18:32 /dev/stlinkv2-1_2 -> sg2
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec 30 18:32 /dev/stlinkv2-1_5 -> bus/usb/001/040
```

When only the 48 pin USB dongle is connected:

```
    chandran@chandran-OptiPlex-9020:~$ ll /dev/stlinkv2-1_*
    ls: cannot access '/dev/stlinkv2-1_*': No such file or directory
```

The dongle shows up as `/dev/ttyACM0` on my machine.

How can I proceed to make the USB dongle work? Do I need additional drivers or udev rules?

I have asked the same question on the [ST-Forum](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BudPLjSQM/how-to-make-the-stm32wb55-usb-dongle-show-up-in-linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't connecting to your STM's directly for programming. You are connecting to a small STM32F1 which is programmed with STLINK/V2 software to act as an programmer.

The usb dongle doesn't have that chip added to it so you'll have to wire up the programming pins for the SWD connection yourself from a SWD programmer.

Your main board (with the STM32F1) can be configured using jumpers to program an external STM32. You'll need to connect the `GND` `3V3` `SWCLK` and `SWIO` to program it.

You can even check this for yourself by going over to ST's site and download the schematics under the resources tab. [dongle link](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group0/6f/4a/27/3b/7d/c4/43/f8/mb1293_schematics/files/MB1293-WB55CGU-C02_schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1293-WB55CGU-C02_schematic.pdf) [mainboard link](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group0/e3/a0/c8/d8/8d/da/4f/43/mb1355_schematics/files/MB1355-WB55RGV-C02_schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1355-WB55RGV-C02_schematic.pdf)

Comment: You can also check this official ST video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFWuH05nlQ4